# WPF binding fails with custom add and remove accessors for INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, events, inotifypropertychanged

I have a scenario which is causing strange behavior with WPF data binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I want a private member of the data binding source to handle the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

Here's the source code:

#### XAML

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Height="100" Width="100">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckboxIsChecked}" Content="A" />
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CheckboxIsChecked}" Content="B" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### Normal implementation works

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool CheckboxIsChecked
    {
        get { return this.mCheckboxIsChecked; }
        set
        {
            this.mCheckboxIsChecked = value;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CheckboxIsChecked"));
        }
    }

    private bool mCheckboxIsChecked = false;

    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
}
```

#### Desired implementation doesn't work

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { lock (this.mHandler) { this.mHandler.PropertyChanged += value; } }
        remove { lock (this.mHandler) { this.mHandler.PropertyChanged -= value; } }
    }

    public bool CheckboxIsChecked
    {
        get { return this.mHandler.CheckboxIsChecked; }
        set { this.mHandler.CheckboxIsChecked = value; }
    }

    private HandlesPropertyChangeEvents mHandler = new HandlesPropertyChangeEvents();

    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public class HandlesPropertyChangeEvents : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool CheckboxIsChecked
        {
            get { return this.mCheckboxIsChecked; }
            set
            {
                this.mCheckboxIsChecked = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CheckboxIsChecked"));
            }
        }

        private bool mCheckboxIsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "mCheckboxIsChecked"? edit: Nevermind I see it's a bool.

Comment: do you still get this error if you make the "mHandler" public?

Comment: I also don't understand the need to override the PropertyChanged Event? why put a lock and register the event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just a guess, but I think it might be because the `sender` parameter passed to the event handler is an instance of `HandlesPropertyChangeEvents`, when the binding expects an instance of `MainWindow`.

Try to change your code so that the sender is the `MainWindow` instance :

```
private PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add { lock (this.mHandler) { this._propertyChanged += value; } }
    remove { lock (this.mHandler) { this._propertyChanged -= value; } }
}


...

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mHandler.PropertyChanged += mHandler_PropertyChanged;
}

private void mHandler_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = _propertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        _propertyChanged(this, e);
}
```

Comment: A complicating factor was that I updated Windows and hadn't restarted... I don't get exceptions anymore, and your guess was right! WPF was expecting the sender to be the MainWindow object.

Comment: FWIW your example code is not exactly what I was looking to do, but your guess helped me fix the issue.

Comment: @emddudley: could you please post the solution as I am curious about this one! thanks

Answer (score 2):

My working solution is almost exactly the same as the "desired implementation" in my question, with the addition of the Sender property.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { lock (this.mHandler) { this.mHandler.PropertyChanged += value; } }
        remove { lock (this.mHandler) { this.mHandler.PropertyChanged -= value; } }
    }

    public bool CheckboxIsChecked
    {
        get { return this.mHandler.CheckboxIsChecked; }
        set { this.mHandler.CheckboxIsChecked = value; }
    }

    private HandlesPropertyChangeEvents mHandler = new HandlesPropertyChangeEvents();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mHandler.Sender = this;
    }

    public class HandlesPropertyChangeEvents : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Sender { get; set; }

        public bool CheckboxIsChecked
        {
            get { return this.mCheckboxIsChecked; }
            set
            {
                this.mCheckboxIsChecked = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this.Sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CheckboxIsChecked"));
            }
        }

        private bool mCheckboxIsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

This example is a bit artificial, but in my application moving the event handling code outside of the bound class makes sense.